# I wanna display json data to a card in html page using ajax

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

[Output of my requirement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SkjG.png)

I have tried many times to get the required result in html page.

am calling a function when i check a box in html ,the function giving back result of json data and this json data i wanna display dynamically into my card style.

Here is hmtl code:

```
    <div id="filter"style="margin-top:100px;margin-left:100px">
  <h2>Filter options</h2>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="Samsung" checked>
    <label for="Samsung">Samsung</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="iPhone" checked>
    <label for="iPhone">iPhone</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="HTC" checked>
    <label for="HTC">HTC</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="LG" checked>
    <label for="LG">LG</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="Nokia" checked>
    <label for="Nokia">Nokia</label>
  </div>
</div>


<table id="phones" >
  <thead>

  </thead>
  <tbody >

   <div style="margin-top:100px;margin-left:100px;margin-right:100px" >
   <div> 
  <label style="margin-bottom:50px;margin-left:80px"><h2>Find your best hotel</h2></label>
  </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4"  style="background-color:lavender;height:310px;width:310px"><label id="hotel_image"></label></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6" style="background-color:lavenderblush;"><label id="hotel_name"></label></div><br>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3"   style="background-color:lavender;margin-left:100px;margin-top:10px"><label id="hotel_price"></label></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3"   style="background-color:#ccc;margin-top:220px;margin-left:300px"><label id="book_me"></label></div>

    </div>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is javascript code:

```
    <script>

  function getPhoneFilterOptions(){
    var opts = [];
    $checkboxes.each(function(){
      if(this.checked){
        opts.push(this.id);
      }
    });

    return opts;
  }

  function updatePhones(opts){
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "submit.php",
      dataType : 'json',
      cache: false,
      data: {filterOpts: opts},
      success: function(data){



        $.each(data, function() {

        $.each(this, function(k , v) {

         if(k==='img_path'){
          v = "<a href='image_description.html'><image src='img_path' height='300px' width='300px' ></a>";

            ("#hotel_image").html(v);

        } else if (k==='price'){

          ("#hotel_price").html(v);

        } else if (k==='brand'){

            ("#hotel_name").html(v);

        }

      })

    });

  }
  })
  }

  var $checkboxes = $("input:checkbox");
  $checkboxes.on("change", function(){
    var opts = getPhoneFilterOptions();
    updatePhones(opts);
  });

  $checkboxes.trigger("change");
</script>
```

am geeting data json data from submit.php like this:

```
[
   {
     "img_path":"photo1.jpg",
     "price":"2000",
     "brand":"AAMSOTO"
   },

   {
     "img_path":"photo4.jpg",
     "price":"2500",
     "brand":"AfMSOTO"
   },

   {
     "img_path":"photo2.jpg",
     "price":"3000",
     "brand":"CAMSOTO"
   },
   {
     "img_path":"photo3.jpg",
     "price":"4000",
     "brand":"BAMSOTO"
   }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `data` is a javascript object the following inside your success method should work:

Make sure data is a javascript object, if its not you will have to use `JSON.parse()` to turn the JSON data into one.

```
$.each(data, function() {
           var imageUrl = this['img_path']
           var price = this['price']
           var brand = this['brand']

           const img = document.createElement('img');
           img.src = imgUrl;
           document.getElementById('#hotel_image').appendChild(img);
     document.getElementById('#hotel_price').appendChild(document.createTextNode(price));

                    document.getElementById('#hotel_name').appendChild(document.createTextNode(brand));
        }
```